# How to get the id from the data base basd on the listview items

Tags: android

This is one of the class in my app. In this class list of recipes are displaying which were are also stored into the sqlite database. In my db I stored the each recipe name, quantity, image and price. Now i would like to set the edit text value in this class where the edit text value is the quantity value in db. but i don't know how to retreive the quantity value of a particular list items in the db and setting that value in edit text. I am getting all the db count values and stores in arraylist but how to get the particular recipe quantity?

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.restaurantapp.YourOrder.OrdersImageAdapter.ImageHolder;

    public class YourOrder extends HelperActivity {

        private ListView list;
        private DataBaseHandler db;
        ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        OrdersImageAdapter adapter;
        public static TextView toatalamount;
        EditText qtyView, quantityt;
        int total;
        int quantity;
        double recipeamount = 0;
        public static Button payment;
        public Integer id = null;
        public String name = null;
        public Integer price = null;
        public int quantiy;
        public String quan;
        String UpdateVAlue;
        double ordercount;
        private Double orderTotal = 0.00;
        static String ordertotalval;
        public String setvaluefinal;
        int dbcount = 0;
        public double editcount = 0;
        int count = NewBreakfastItems.getVariable();
        ImageHolder holder;
        ArrayList<String> getarray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> getid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> quantityid = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.yourorders);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            toatalamount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rupees);
            db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
            payment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buy);

            // Reading all contacts from database
            List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
            Log.d("", "------DATABASE CONTACTS-------" + db.getAllContacts());
            for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
                        + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage() + "Price :" + cn.getprice();

                Log.d("Name: ", log);

                Log.i("", "-----ID-------" + cn.getID());
                Log.i("", "-----ID-------" + cn.getName());
                Log.i("----recipe price---", "-----price----" + cn.getprice());

                id = cn.getID();
                name = cn.getName();
                price = cn.getprice();
                ordercount = ordercount + price;
                getarray.add(cn.getName());
                getid.add(cn.getID());
                quantityid.add(cn.getQuantity());

                Log.e("---ordercount---", "----ordercount----" + ordercount);
                toatalamount.setText(String.valueOf(ordercount));

                /*
                 * count=count+price; Log.i("---count----", "-----count----"+count);
                 */
                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.e("Result:========== ", "=====LOG=====" + log);

                imageArry.add(cn);

            }

            Log.d("", "-----ID-------" + id);
            Log.d("", "-----ID-------" + name);

            adapter = new OrdersImageAdapter(this, R.layout.orderscart, imageArry);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            dbcount = db.getContactsCount();

            Log.e("----dbcount----", "-----dbcount---" + dbcount);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("","item clicked-----");
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "u clicked on"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            payment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Payment.class);
                    // intent.putExtra("count", count);
                    intent.putExtra("ordertotalval", ordertotalval);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            footerBlock();

        }

        public class OrdersImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

            // Contact contact;
            Context context;
            public int dltcount;
            int layoutResourceId;
            int adaptercount = 0;
            public int extPrice;

            ArrayList<Contact> data = new ArrayList<Contact>();

            public OrdersImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                    ArrayList<Contact> data) {

                super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
                this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
                this.context = context;
                this.data = data;

                this.data = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                this.data.addAll(data);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
                Contact product = data.get(position);
                View row = convertView;
                holder = null;
                Contact lContact = (Contact) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.e("", "----lcontact values-----"+lContact);
                db = new DataBaseHandler(getContext());
                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                            .getLayoutInflater();
                    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                    EditText quantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                    // attach the TextWatcher listener to the EditText
                    // quantity.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(row));

                    int idval=getid.indexOf(lContact);
                    Log.e("", "----------id value getting-----"+idval);
                    holder = new ImageHolder();
                    holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                    holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                    holder.dlttxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dlt);
                    holder.quantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                    holder.recipeprice = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.recipeprice);
                    row.setTag(holder);

                } else {
                    holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
                }
                quantityt = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                quantityt.setTag(product);
                if (product.getQuantity() != 0) {
                    quantityt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getQuantity()));
                } else {
                    quantityt.setText("");
                }

                TextView ext = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.setprice);
                if (product.getQuantity() != 0) {
                    ext.setText("$" + df.format(product.getExt()));
                } else {
                    ext.setText("");
                }

                holder.recipeprice
                        .setText(String.valueOf(lContact.getprice() + "X"));

                /* ====DELETING RECIPE ITEMS==== */
                holder.dlttxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        setvaluefinal = qtyView.getText().toString();
                        ordercount = Integer.parseInt(setvaluefinal);

                        Log.e("", "------yyyyyy-------" + ordercount);
                        Log.e("---pos---", "----position----" + position);

                        Contact lContact = (Contact) list
                                .getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Log.e("---pos---", "----position----" + lContact);
                        Log.e("TAG", "" + lContact.getID());
                        db.deleteContact(lContact.getID());
                        // db.deleteContact(pos);
                        Log.e("", "======deleted=====" + lContact.getID());
                        Log.e("", "====NAME====" + lContact.getName());
                        quan = lContact.getName();
                        Log.e("---lcontact price---", "------lcntact price----"
                                + lContact.getprice());
                        adaptercount = lContact.getprice();

                        Log.e("", "quantity---" + quantityt.getText());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                lContact.getName() + ":" + "Deleted Sucessfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // editcount=adaptercount * ordercount;
                        Log.e("", "----edit count----" + editcount);
                        // Log.e("", "----order total value----"+orderTotal);

                        // recipeamount=orderTotal-editcount;
                        // Log.e("", "------recipe amount-------"+recipeamount);

                        imageArry.remove(lContact);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// updating adapter
                        count = db.getContactsCount();
                        Log.d("", "----updated count----" + db.getContactsCount());
                        HelperActivity.num.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                        // toatalamount.setText(String.valueOf(recipeamount));

                        // YourOrder.toatalamount.setText();

                    }

                });

                holder.quantity.setText("1");
                Contact picture = data.get(position);
                holder.txtTitle.setText(picture._name);
                // convert byte to bitmap take from contact class
                byte[] outImage = picture._image;
                ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        outImage);
                Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
                // db.deleteContact(null);
                return row;
            }

            public class ImageHolder {
                ImageView imgIcon;
                TextView txtTitle;
                TextView dlttxt;
                EditText quantity;
                TextView recipeprice;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Your question is too complicated.

Comment: even i can see in ur code, u r fetching data frm db, wat is ur exact issue can u explain it.

Comment: In my db i have 5 columns i want to get one column data which is named as quantity and i want to set that quantity to edit text

Comment: `ArrayList<Contact> data` what are all the thing you have it in this array list.

Comment: But i am unable to get the values from the that array